# PHP code to let visitors select background

Tags: html, background

I have a script which allows visitors to choose a background on my website. I am having problems with the main content on my website. On Chrome there is some change in the position of things and now I.E is all fine.

When I remove the background script

```
<style> body { background: url('http://domain.com/assets/<?php echo "".$_SESSION["USER"]["bg"]."" ?>.jpg') top left; } </style>
```

The script works, for changing BGs and I cannot figure out why it alters the tracking slide.

[image: Comparison]

**update: resolved**

Comment: How does this have anything to do with PHP, let alone sessions?

Comment: it has something to do with sessions as it needs one's session to work

Comment: I assume the ones down voting my question have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an embedded style for example and use 'background' with setting the position top and left.

```
<?php
     $bgid = $_SESSION['User']['bg'];
?>
<style> body {
      background: url('http://domain.com/assets/<?php echo $_SESSION["USER"]["bg"] ?>.jpg') top left;
} </style>
```

IE is very picky, make sure you have a single quote ' on each side of the url and make sure to explicitly specify the position top left or if you don't want the background to repeat add no-repeat at the end.

I'm just making assumptions so it may or may not work depending on what the exact issue is. I hope this helps :)

Comment: you're right will the IE being picky -.- thanks I'll give it a go

Comment: I did this to the `<style>`  

`<style> body {
      background: url('http://domain.com/assets/<?php echo "".$_SESSION["USER"]["bg"]."" ?>.jpg'); 
} </style>` ..but yeah, same issue, thanks for you suggestion :/

Comment: add 'top left' after you defined the url -> background: url('') top left;

Comment: Ok, backgrounds show on both IE / Chrome but there's some issues with one of the divs.. I'll post a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Use Doctype declaration .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

If it doesnt work try using different doctype declaration .

About doctype:

The  declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

In HTML 4.01, the  declaration refers to a DTD, because HTML 4.01 was based on SGML. The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Put this code in footer before body tag close    

<script> 
document.body.background = '<?=$bgid?>'+'.jpg'; 
</script>
```